# VLC: Cant Play Video from getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android, video, file-permissions

I have saved my video file to my storage and tried to play the video from my app by using Intent .. On other players that file playing fine but when i tried to play that file with VLC it gives me following error;

> Playback Error Vlc encountered an error with this media. Please try
>   refreshing the media library.

And

> The location /storage/emulated/0/myFolder/file.mov cannot be played.

**Saving Method**

```
private String SaveToDir(String DownloadUrl) {

    try {

        File dir = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "myFolder");
        if (dir.exists() == false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl);
        String fileName = DownloadUrl.substring(DownloadUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "download file name:" + fileName);

            URLConnection uconn = url.openConnection();
            uconn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
            uconn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

            InputStream is = uconn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferinstream = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            BufferedOutputStream outStream = null;
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            byte[] buf = new byte[5000];
            int len;
            while ((len = bufferinstream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            makeFileAvailable(file);
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + "sec");
            int dotindex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (dotindex >= 0) {
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, dotindex);

            }
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```

**Intent**

```
 String responselink = SaveToDir(getImgUrl());
 String type = FileUtils.getMimeType(responselink);

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(responselink));
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(responselink), type);                              
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);                                
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
 generalPropListener.getSelfContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prepending "file://" to responseLink.

Comment: Yes it will work but there might be a problem with Android 7.0

Comment: Then you'll have to use a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). It's tedious, but it's not hard.